# How to change the date format in termcal?

Tags: calendar, termcal

I'd like to remove the ordinal numbering and month names in `termcal` but have been unsuccessful so far. The original code, according to the package documentation is:

```
\newcommand{\calprintdate}{%
\ifnewmonth\framebox{\monthname\ \ordinaldate}%
\else \ordinaldate\fi
}
```

Which yields dates like "Oct 1st" or "Aug 26th." My goal is to change these to "10/1" and "8/26," respectively. Since I am new to LaTeX, my attempt is a bit embarrassing:

```
\renewcommand{\calprintdate}{%
    \ifnewmonth\framebox{\c@month\ \c@date}%
    \else \ordinaldate\fi
}
```

This outputs gibberish like "@month @date," which confuses me, because the documentation does state that `\c@month` is the month counter (Jan = 1). I also haven't changed `\ordinaldate` in the `\else` line, and I don't know what `\fi` means.

Here's a minimal working example without `\renewcommand`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{termcal}

\begin{document}

\begin{calendar}{8/31/2014}{5}
\setlength{\calboxdepth}{.3in}

% Description of the Week.
\calday[Sun]{\noclassday} % Sunday
\skipday\skipday % Monday, Tuesday
\calday[Wed]{\noclassday} % Wednesday
\skipday\skipday % Thursday, Friday
\calday[Sat]{\noclassday}

\caltext{8/31/2014}{Exam 1}
\caltext{9/7/2014}{Exam 2}

\end{calendar}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of MWE]

I also don't understand why "Sep 3rd" is printed, if, as according to `\calprintdate`, only dates for new months should be printed.

Comment: Can you please add a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that people can see what packages etc you need to get your code to work (but don't add code that is not needed). This makes it much easier for people to help you. In this case it would be useful to have code for producing a (very) short calendar.

Comment: @Andrew I added a MWE. Sorry for leaving this out earlier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that this is very easy: internally [termcal](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/termcal) uses counters `month`, `date` (for day of the month) and `year`. So to do what you want you only need the following:

```
\renewcommand{\calprintdate}{%
     \ifnewmonth\framebox{\arabic{month}/\arabic{date}}%
     \else\arabic{date}%
     \fi}
```

Now your calendar becomes:

[image]

I think that this is what you wanted. If you want to always print the month number then instead use:

```
\renewcommand{\calprintdate}{%
     \ifnewmonth\framebox{\arabic{month}/\arabic{date}}%
     \else\arabic{month}/\arabic{date}%
     \fi}
```

Finally, if you don't want boxes around the first date in each month you can simplify this to

```
\renewcommand{\calprintdate}{\arabic{month}/\arabic{date}}
```

[**Edit** Aside: *Explanation of the "@month @date gibberish"*:

In LaTeX you create counters using

```
\newcounter{countername}
```

Internally this is stored as the TeX counter called `\c@countername` (here `countername` can be arbitrary). In code behind the scenes it is sometimes useful to use the `\c@countername` form but this is rarely necessary for normal mortals. If you do to use `\c@countername` then you should surround your code with `\makeatletter...\makeatother` because the @ character is "protected" so that it can't be used in normal commands -- this is why `@month` etc was printed when you tried this. (For more information about @ search for "category codes" in TeX.) Finally, as above, to print the counter you can use `\arabic{countername}` to print as a normal number (`1`, `2`, `3`, `...`), `\alph{countername}` to print in the sequence `a`, `b`, `c`, `..., and so on.
]

Comment: Any idea why "9/3" is printed? Or is that possibly controlled by somewhere else in the package (other than \calprintdate)? Thanks!

Comment: I've copied the `termcal` syntax so that when you hit a new month the date is printed inside a `\framebox`, and the number of the month is printed, to highlight this. Is this what you wanted? If you want to always use the format `<month>/<day>` let me know and I'll edit the solution.

Comment: I'd like to always use the format <month>/<day>, thank you. And I think the 9/3 date is in a framebox, because it's the first day of September that is displayed.

Comment: @Sel I've edited answer to describe more options.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your comprehensive answer and for explaining category codes.